# Using coIH as an argument to the transitivity of Bisimilarity (cofix and pcofix)

Tags: coq, proof-assistant, coinductive-type

It might be a very silly question for the logic gurus but less so for me. First I generally describe the issue, than I provide a proper example with code.

Assume three streams of nats: xs, ys, zs. Using paco, I want to prove the bisimilarity of xs & ys, where seq' is the bisimilarity relation:

```ml
Lemma xs_ys:
 seq' xs ys.
Proof.
 pcofix coIH.
 (* get heads out *)
 pfold; constructor; right.
 (* Now I need to show "r xs' ys'" *)
```

My lemma was stated not generally enough, so I cannot use `coIH`. I could use `coIH` to show: `r xs' zs` and I also have previously proved
`seq' ys' zs`, so I hoped to use `coIH` as an argument to some form of transitivity.

Using paco I could not figure a way to do it, since there are different types (`seq'` vs `r`), using basic `cofix` I could, but I could not `Qed`.

**My question is**

a) Does it break any coinduction principle?

b) If not, is it still somehow possible in `paco` manipulating `seq'` vs `r` relationship.

Below is a *simplified **updated** reproducible example*.

```ml
Require Import Arith Bool List.
Require Import Setoid Program.
Require Import Paco.paco.
(*****************)
(***** SETUP *****)
(*****************)
CoInductive stream (V : Type) : Type :=
| Cons : V -> stream V -> stream V.

Inductive seq_gen seq : stream nat -> stream nat -> Prop :=
  | _seq_gen : forall n s1 s2 (R : seq s1 s2 : Prop), seq_gen seq (Cons nat n s1) (Cons nat n s2).
#[export] Hint Constructors seq_gen : core.

CoInductive seq : stream nat -> stream nat -> Prop :=
| seq_fold : forall s1 s2, seq_gen seq s1 s2 -> seq s1 s2.
Definition seq' s1 s2 := paco2 seq_gen bot2 s1 s2.
#[export] Hint Unfold seq' : core.
Lemma seq_gen_mon: monotone2 seq_gen. Proof. pmonauto. Qed.
#[export] Hint Resolve seq_gen_mon : paco.

Theorem seq'_cons : forall n1 n2 s1 s2 (SEQ : seq' (Cons nat n1 s1) (Cons nat n2 s2)),
  n1 = n2 /\ seq' s1 s2.
Proof.
  intros.
  punfold SEQ.
  inversion_clear SEQ.
  pclearbot.
  auto.
Qed.

Definition stream_decompose (V : Type) (s : stream V) :=
  match s with
  | Cons _ v s' =>
    Cons V v s'
  end.

Theorem stream_decomposition :
  forall (V : Type)
         (s : stream V),
    s = stream_decompose V s.
Proof.
  intros V [v s'].
  unfold stream_decompose.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Ltac unfold_and_fold f :=
  unfold stream_decompose;
  unfold f; fold f.


Lemma seq'_is_transitive :
  forall xs ys zs : stream nat,
    seq' xs ys ->
    seq' ys zs ->
    seq' xs zs.
Proof.
  pcofix coIH.
  intros [x xs'] [y ys'] [z zs'] seq'_xs_ys seq'_ys_zs.

  destruct (seq'_cons x y xs' ys' seq'_xs_ys) as [eq_x_y seq'_xs'_ys']; clear seq'_xs_ys.
  destruct (seq'_cons y z ys' zs' seq'_ys_zs) as [eq_y_z seq'_ys'_zs']; clear seq'_ys_zs.

  rewrite -> eq_x_y, eq_y_z.

  pfold; constructor; right.

  exact (coIH xs' ys' zs' seq'_xs'_ys' seq'_ys'_zs').
Qed. 

(**********************)
(***** MAIN POINT / EXAMPLE *****)
(**********************)

Fixpoint sum (n x : nat) : nat :=
  match n with
  | O => 0
  | S n' => x + (sum n' x)
  end.


CoFixpoint nats_v0_aux (n : nat) : stream nat :=
  Cons nat n (nats_v0_aux (S n)).

Definition nats_v0 : stream nat :=
  nats_v0_aux 0.

CoFixpoint nats_v1_aux (n : nat) : stream nat :=
  Cons nat (sum n 1) (nats_v1_aux (S n)).

Definition nats_v1 : stream nat :=
  nats_v1_aux 0.

Lemma about_sum :
  forall (j : nat),
    sum j 1 = j.
Proof.
  induction j as [ | j' IHj'].
  - simpl; reflexivity.
  - simpl; rewrite IHj'; reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma seq'_ys_zs :
  forall (i : nat),
    seq' (nats_v0_aux (S i)) (nats_v0_aux (S i)).
Proof.
  pcofix coIH.
  intro i.
  rewrite -> (stream_decomposition nat (nats_v0_aux (S i))).
  unfold_and_fold nats_v0_aux.
  pfold; constructor; right.
  exact (coIH (S i)).
Qed.
  
Theorem seq'_nats_v0_nats_v1 :
  forall (i : nat),
    seq' (nats_v0_aux i) (nats_v1_aux i).
Proof.
  pcofix xs_ys.
  intro i.
  rewrite -> (stream_decomposition nat (nats_v0_aux i)).
  rewrite -> (stream_decomposition nat (nats_v1_aux i)).
  unfold_and_fold nats_v0_aux.
  unfold_and_fold nats_v1_aux.
  rewrite about_sum.
  pfold; constructor; right.
  (* I could easily use xs_ys here *)
  (* But this is not the point of the example *)
  (* Instead, I want to either
     a) rewrite 
        nats_v0_aux (S i) with
        nats_v0_aux (S i) using
        seq'_ys_zs
        and then 
        exact xs_ys
     b) use transitivity to show
        xs_ys -> seq'_ys_zs -> my goal.
   *)
Abort.
```

Comment: You need to establish a stronger fact than transitivity of seq': validity of seq_gen bisimulation up-to seq_gen.

I will write down a detailed answer tonight, but your code is not quite compiling, you are missing notably `stream_decomposiiton` and `ones`. Can you fix it to ease answering please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am slightly unsure about your question as your code does not compile but seems to only require the reflexivity of `seq'`, but your question seems to ask whether you can, in the middle of a proof by coinduction, rewrite by a previously established `seq'` equation.

I will therefore try to answer the latter question, first from a theoretical standpoint, then using paco.

### Normal coinduction principle for νb (here, b == seq_gen):

First, recall that what you have access by default is essentially the basic coinduction principle from Knaster Tarski, i.e.:

```
 x <= y /\ y <= by
-----------------
     x <= νb
```

So the core of the proof consistes in proving "y <= by" for a well chosen candidate y.
For a binary relation, that looks like that in the middle of a proof:

```
   y a b
  --------
  b y a b
```

Making things a bit more concrete, in the case at hand, a and b are streams, b is seq_gen, and y the parameter r paco introduced.
In your proof, you know some structure about y, and therefore about a and b, allowing you to prove they have the same head and therefore "step through b".
You have now as a goal:

```
   y a b
  --------
  y a' b'
```

for some particular a' and b'.
If you had chosen y wisely, i.e., if y was indeed a valid coinduction candidate, you must have fallen back into it and can conclude.

### Up-to principle

What you ask (I think) is: what if I missed, but not by much? I.e., in particular here, what if the pair `(a',b')` is not in y, but y
contains a pair `(a',b')` such that `seq a a'` and `seq b' b`. Surely that should be fair to conclude even if I didn't really pick a coinductively stable set?

Well, it can be fair (as in sound) or it may be unsound depending on [b]: you are asking what is referred to in the literature whether
b-bisimulation up-to b-bisimilarity is a valid principle.
Famously, it is valid when considering strong bisimilarity, but not when considering weak bisimilarity: see chapter 4 of Sangiorgi's "Introduction to Bisimulation and Coinduction" for a detailed and gentle explanation.

Now in your case, it absolutely is valid! But we need to prove it. Luckily, paco (as well as Pous's coq-coinduction library) provide tools to do so.

Before jumping into the code, let's rephrase what we are aiming to prove, i.e., that the following principle is valid:

```
    x <= y /\ y <= bfy
  -----------------
       x <= νb
```

That is: after stepping through b, we don't have to fall back exactly into y, but can fall into something slightly bigger, some (f y) for a well
chosen f. Libraries like paco provide a sufficient condition to establish this principle, and some support to use it smoothly.

With that in mind, we start by defining the specific f of interest, i.e. the one that allows us to look for bisimilar (seq-related) pairs in our set. We call it [seqTC] for seq_transitive_closure.

Based on your definitions, you can use the following code to implement the ideas described above.

(* UPDATED CODE 02/28 following OP's edit *)

```ml
(* BEGIN NEW CODE *)
Variant seqTC (r : stream nat -> stream nat -> Prop)
  : stream nat -> stream nat -> Prop :=
| seqTC_intro s1 s1' s2 s2'
      (EQl: seq' s1 s1')
      (EQr: seq' s2 s2')
      (REL: r s1' s2')
  : seqTC r s1 s2
.

(* It must be monotone, and we inform paco of this fact *)
Lemma seqTC_mon r1 r2 s1 s2
      (IN: seqTC r1 s1 s2)
      (LE: r1 <2= r2):
  seqTC r2 s1 s2.
Proof.
  destruct IN. econstructor; eauto.
Qed.
Hint Resolve seqTC_mon : paco.

(* Now here is the crucial proof obligation: compatibility is a sufficient condition to establish the validity of our up-to principle!
  I would recommend for instance Pous's «CoInduction All The Way Up» for more details on this sufficient condition.
 *)
Lemma seqTC_compat:
  compatible2 seq_gen seqTC.
Proof.
  econstructor; eauto with paco.
  intros ? s1 s2 H.
  inversion_clear H.
  punfold EQl; inversion EQl.
  punfold EQr; inversion EQr.
  inversion REL.
  subst.
  inversion H3; inversion H4; subst.
  constructor.
  pclearbot.
  econstructor; eauto.
Qed.
(* For technical reasons, paco let you establish something slightly weaker than compatibility.
  We hence derive trivially this alternative, and inform paco of this fact.
*)
Lemma seqTC_wcompat:
  wcompatible2 seq_gen seqTC.
Proof.
  apply compat2_wcompat; eauto with paco; apply seqTC_compat.
Qed.
Hint Resolve seqTC_wcompat : paco.

(* Up-to reflexivity is always true *)
#[global] Instance Reflexive_seq_gen f (r rg: stream nat -> stream nat -> Prop) :
  Reflexive (gpaco2 seq_gen f r rg).
Proof.
  gcofix CIH. gstep; intros.
  destruct x; constructor.
  eauto with paco.
Qed.

(* So in particular seq is reflexive *)
#[global] Instance Reflexive_seq :
  Reflexive seq'.
Proof.
  intro.
  ginit.
  apply Reflexive_seq_gen.
Qed.

From Coq Require Import Morphisms.
(* So in particular seq is reflexive *)
#[global] Instance seq_seq_gen (r rg: stream nat -> stream nat -> Prop) :
  Proper (seq' ==> seq' ==> flip impl) (gpaco2 seq_gen seqTC r rg).
Proof.
  intros ?? EQ1 ?? EQ2 EQ3.
  gclo; econstructor; eauto.
Qed.

(* END NEW CODE *)

(* BEGIN EXAMPLE *)
Theorem seq'_nats_v0_nats_v1 :
  forall (i : nat),
    seq' (nats_v0_aux i) (nats_v1_aux i).
Proof.
  (* YOUR CODE *)
  pcofix xs_ys.
  intro i.
  rewrite -> (stream_decomposition nat (nats_v0_aux i)).
  rewrite -> (stream_decomposition nat (nats_v1_aux i)).
  unfold_and_fold nats_v0_aux.
  unfold_and_fold nats_v1_aux.
  rewrite about_sum.
  pfold; constructor.
  (* You have stepped, as you say you can conclude by *)
  right; exact (xs_ys (S i)).
  (* But this is not the point of the example *)
  Restart.
  (* a. and b. are essentially the same, one explicit the other implicit.
     Let's do b. first, the explicit use of transitivity *)
  (* We move to the generalized world. Note that it picks up automatically [seqTC] in doing so *)
  (* We follow the same step with the renaming:
     pcofix -> gcofix
     pfold/pstep -> gstep
   *)
  ginit.
  gcofix xs_ys.
  intro i.
  rewrite -> (stream_decomposition nat (nats_v0_aux i)).
  rewrite -> (stream_decomposition nat (nats_v1_aux i)).
  unfold_and_fold nats_v0_aux.
  unfold_and_fold nats_v1_aux.
  rewrite about_sum.
  gstep; constructor.
  (* You have stepped, again, could conclude, but let's illustrate b.
     We invoke the closure
   *)
  gclo.
  econstructor.
  (* We can use transitivity on each side. We use [seq'_ys_zs] on the left, reflexivity on the right *)
  apply seq'_ys_zs.
  reflexivity.
  (* Of course this is a bit silly as we just rewrote [x ≡ x], but we did it nonetheless! We can conclude *)
  gbase.
  exact (xs_ys (S i)).
  Restart.
  (* and finally option (a), amounts to the same but wrapped in typeclass extravaganza *)
   ginit.
  gcofix xs_ys.
  intro i.
  rewrite -> (stream_decomposition nat (nats_v0_aux i)).
  rewrite -> (stream_decomposition nat (nats_v1_aux i)).
  unfold_and_fold nats_v0_aux.
  unfold_and_fold nats_v1_aux.
  rewrite about_sum.
  gstep; constructor.
  (* You have stepped, again, could conclude, but let's illustrate a.
     Thanks to seq_seq_gen, you can simply rewrite.
     Well you could, except that coq complain it fails to progress as
     the equation is of the shape [x ≡ x], but as far as paco and seq' is concerned,
     you can!
   *)
  Fail rewrite seq'_ys_zs.
Abort.
```

Comment: Dear Yannick, thank you so much for this detailed answer. Sorry for the late update, living 
 in a very different timezone. Let me address some of the points:


1. I have updated the code section to make sure it compiles. I also replaced the example of 'ones' with a little more comprehensible one. 
2. The last theorem there explains that I do know that I could prove this example in a very simple way, but that is not the point. The point would be for a more general case, where my coIH can fit s1 but cannot fit s2, and instead it can show s1~s3, where I have previously shown s2~s3.

Comment: 3. An important note is that `s1` and `s2` refer to the tails of the original streams as you can see in the example. Assume I do not have a theorem `s2_original ~ s3`, but specifically `s2~s3`. Hence, I need to unfold the original streams. 
4. I will be jumping into "Introduction to Bisimulation and Coinduction" in a bit, and I also read the paper behind `paco`, but I am still catching up with the definitions you provided above. Do you mind showing `Lemma foo s1 s2` in the context of what I provided (`Theorem seq'_nats_v0_nats_v1 `)?

Comment: Hello!
It does feel like you are indeed looking for what I have described in my answer. I have updated the code to use the one from your edit. As you can see in your example I can either explicitly use the closure to "transit" via `seq'_ys_zs`, or could directly rewrite with it if it was not a trivial equation.

Comment: You may also be interested in the paper we had written about `gpaco`: https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.02659

Comment: Thank you so much! It answers my question precisely. Just some readings left to do for me.